# .htaccess file location

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to use an `.htaccess` file to create clan URL for my website. I want to test it on my local version of the site and the upload to the server if I succeed.

The question is, where do I have to put the `.htaccess` file? (I am using LAMP)

Right now my page's index.php file is in `var/www/project/`

Should I place the `.htaccess` file here, and can I have multiple `.htaccess` files?

If I have another project in folder `var/www/project2` and want to set redirect rules for that site too, and some of the rules are different than the ones set on the first project, how can I handle that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure your rules both in .htaccess and per directory / file / alias... in the apache configuration.

If you uses .htaccess files, you can set them anywhere starting from your server root, and it will have effect on any child folder.

Thus if /var/www is your server root, then /var/www/.htaccess will be checked for both project & project2.

Conversely, /var/www/project/.htaccess will only have effect on this folder and its children, not on /var/www/project2 .

Comment: Sorry, my rep is so low I can't even vote up. Thank you for your answer, It clears things a lot for me.

Comment: @AnPel - you *can*, however, accept Geoffroy's answer, which you should do if you're satisfied with it.

Comment: Can the .htaccess be dynamically generated in any ways?

Comment: You can, but the better way is to update apache's configuration directly, because .htaccess have an impact on performance.